# Mysql - Troublesome replace

Tags: mysql, sql, replace

I'm trying to remove all occurences of **`** in TRIGGER_NAME and replace them with **'**

```
UPDATE Scheduler.dbo.QRTZ_BLOB_TRIGGERS
SET TRIGGER_NAME = REPLACE(TRIGGER_NAME, '`', '\\'')
WHERE
TRIGGER_NAME LIKE '%`%';
```

The logic I'm following is that I need to escape \' to show it but also save it escaped?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-syntax.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually only need a single backslash, ie

```
REPLACE(TRIGGER_NAME, '`', '\'')
```

You can also use a double single-quote which is more standard across database vendors

```
REPLACE(TRIGGER_NAME, '`', '''')
```

Comment: Putting one slash gives me this error `[Err] 42000 - [SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '`'.
42000 - [SQL Server]Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ';`
'.

Comment: @Luke Wait, is this MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: MySQL, the second one worked with `''''`. Like you said though very confusing.